# Webshims lib: HTML5 web form validation not working in IE8

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-8, webshim

I'm new to HTML5 forms and getting them to work in older browsers. I am trying to get my simple HTML5 demo form to validate in IE8 using the Webshims Lib polyfill, but it does not seem to validate. As far a I can tell, I've followed the directions from the [Webshims Lib website](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html). What am I doing wrong? Here's my code (below) and [live link](http://ogmda.com/test/form-test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/polyfiller.js"></script>

<style>
ul {list-style-type: none; margin-top: 100px;}
li {padding-bottom: 10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform" action="process.php" method="post">

<ul>
<li><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"></li>

<li><label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" required></li>

<li><label>Numbers</label>
<input type="number" name="numbers"></li>

<li><label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here" required></textarea></li>

<li><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
</ul>

</form>

<script>
$.webshims.polyfill();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy the whole js-webshim folder into your project. Currently you only have included polyfiller.js. This script only handles the polyfills and includes them from the shim folder.

If you open up your developer console, you will see that you have a lot of 404 requests for js/shims...js.

Some notes as long as you are using only form you should use webshims.polyfill('forms') or webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext') and not webshims.polyfill(). If you have still problems, you should use the files from the dev folder and open your console.

Comment: What are the dependencies for ONLY the HTML5 form validation checks? Do I need to transfer and upload the entire 'js-webshim' folder just to use the validation checks? My chrome console has 3 files listed as missing (shim.css, dom-extend.js, 1.js). Should I just transfer those files and the polyfill.js and that will be all I need? I didn't check the IE8 console. I am working on a site within an intranet with high security and it's difficult to transfer files into the closed network, so the less files required, the better. Files have to be transferred individually! Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: No. This really depends on the feature set you are using. 1.js for example includes mediaelement API. You have to call webshims.polyfill('form') to get only the files, you need. The loaded files differ from browser to browser. If you have experience with grunt you can build your own version with less files. Can't you zip/unzip this?

Comment: I will see if I can get these files through the network (can't transfer zips). Thanks for your time.

Comment: alexander I was able to get all the files transferred. Thanks again for your help. One last question before I close this: Do I need to do php server-side validation before processing the form or is the HTML5 client-side validation all I need? Thanks.

Comment: @redshift You still need to validate all data server-side in PHP. However you do not need to make the error-reporting that pretty: if you already have checks for JS being enabled, then you can assume none of your real users will ever trigger that server-side validation.